# Download files using link in yii TbGridView

Tags: php, yii

I want to add link in TbGridView. When am clicking in the link to show download option.

Here my code,

in view,

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'id'=>'project-documents-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
         array(
             'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
             'label'=>'id_post_author',
             'urlExpression'=>'"/projects/documents/Download/$data->files"',
             'header'=>'Author'
         ),
         array(
              'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
              'template'=>'{delete}'
         ),
     ),
));
```

The $data->files return "uploads/projects/filename1.png";

The function in controller path is projects/documents/download

In my Controller

```
public function actionDownload($name){
    $filecontent=file_get_contents('uploads/projects'.$name);
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    echo $filecontent;
    exit;
}
```

But, I have an error. Any other way to download file from TbGridView.

projects is a module, documents is a controller and downloads is a function

Comment: which error ?  please

Comment: Your request is invalid.

Comment: The request is goes to controller is "http://localhost:88/projects/documents/Download/uploads/projects/07012016074226_6.jpg"

Comment: use `sendfile()` : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/23017-yii-sendfile-issue-downloading-images/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php
public function Download($fullpath){
$filename=$fullpath;
//$fullpath like /uploads/sample.txt
$path = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').$filename;
    if(!empty($path)){ 
        header("Content-type:*/*"); //for all file
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"'); 
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
        readfile($path);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your action  expects you to send a value the parameter `name`

Try assigning the name in get format

```
'urlExpression'=>'"/projects/documents/Download/?name=$data->files"',
```

or format the url and parameter  in the way yii (GET) need

Answer (score 0):

```
// Controller Code
public function actionDownload($name = "")
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $name);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    readfile('uploads/projects' . $name)
}
```